# Notice: Undefined Index in form submission to another page

Tags: php, undefined-index

I am new to php and I am trying to submit a form using POST. My form element looks  like

```
<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["/php/somefunctions.php"]);?>" method="post">
```

Both the files have session_start(); declared at the top and the form doesn't have any required field. When I open the form in browser it shows,

Notice: Undefined index: /php/somefunctions.php in 'filepath' on line 31.

Line 31 is the above mentioned line.
If I ignore this and fill in the form and click on submit, it gives me

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Comment: `$_SERVER["/php/somefunctions.php"]` makes absolutely no sense. What value do you expect it to have? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use server document root.

$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]./path to file

Also you forgot to add echo.  Without echo php won't display anything

echo htmlspecialchars();

Answer (score 0):

use this :
`<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/somefumction.php");?>" method="post">`

or
`<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/php/somefumction.php");?>" method="post">`